# QT Creator don't want launch itself

Tags: qt, crash, qt-creator

I am developing a game using QT Creator since the begining of 2015.

This morning when I want to open my QT project, QT Creator crashed.

I explain : When i click on QT creator icon or on a .pro file, QT creator window appear but aftr few seconds, QT Creator crash and the window title become "QT Creator ( No answer ) " .

How to fix it to re-use QT Creator?

edit : i tried to uninstall, re-install , re-unistall, re-re-install ... Same Result ! Please Help me !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your compiler is still functioning because it seems like it cant compile the code from what I understand, please elaborate with more detail

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I made a back up and QT is now working.

But I still ask myself why QT did't launch itself.

Even if I clicked on QT Creator's icon , QT crashed. There was no link between my project and QT's crash.